# Histogram from Table

Tags: python, datatable, data-science, histogram

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awcxg.png)

Hi, I'm trying to make a histogram with above table, and below is my coding.

```
def histograms(t):
    salaries = t.column('Salary')
    salary_bins = np.arange(min(salaries), max(salaries)+1000, 1000)
    t.hist('Salary', bins=salary_bins, unit='$')
    
histograms(full_data)
```

But it's not showing properly. Can you help me?

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qSdJ.png)

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you trying to show the number of people that have a salary in a certain range? How many salary bins do you want? Why is your function returning age bins?

Comment: @pakpe Sorry, I edited it. I'm just trying to draw a histogram of salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bins argument in a histogram specifies the number of bins into which the data will be evenly distributed.

Let's say you have a sample dataframe of salaries like this:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'name':['joe','jill','martin','emily','frank','john','sue','sally','sam'],
                                 'salary':[105324,65002,98314,24480,55000,62000,75000,79000,32000]})

#output:
     name  salary
0     joe  105324
1    jill   65002
2  martin   98314
3   emily   24480
4   frank   55000
5    john   62000
6     sue   75000
7   sally   79000
8     sam   32000
```

If you want to plot a histogram where the salaries will be distributed in 10 bins and you want to stick with your function, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def histograms(t):
    plt.hist(t.salary, bins = 10, color = 'orange', edgecolor = 'black')
    plt.xlabel('Salary')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.show()

histograms(sample_dataframe)
```

[image]
If you want the x-axis ticks to reflect the boundaries of the 10 bins, you can add this line:

```
import numpy as np
plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(t.salary), max(t.salary), 11), rotation = 45)
```

[image]
Finally to show the y-ticks as integers, you add these lines:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

The final function looks like this:

```
def histograms(t):
    plt.hist(t.salary, bins = 10, color = 'orange', edgecolor = 'black')
    plt.xlabel('Salary')
    plt.ylabel('Count')

    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(t.salary), max(t.salary), 11), rotation = 45)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining from the basics. So I guess the reason my hist was not showing any bars is because there was too many bins! plt and the method you used to make y-axis to integer are not what I've learned yet. Thank you for introducing! I should study more

Comment: That’s correct. You had more bins than data points. Using plt is not a big deal and gives you a lot more flexibility. You can use plt.plot for line graphs, plt.bar for bar graphs, plt.hist for histograms, etc.  You can find many quick matplotlib tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def histograms(t):
    _min = min(t['salary'])
    _max = max(t['salary'])
    bins = int((_max - _min) / 1000) # dividing the salary range in bins of 1000 each
    plt.hist(t['salary'], bins = bins)
histograms(df)
```

Comment: I think so! But how can I change this part "bins = int((_max - _min) / 1000)" if I don't use plt? I want to try not using plt first :)

Comment: replace "plt.hist(t['salary'], bins = bins)" with "   df.plot.hist(by='salary',bins=bins,legend=False,figsize=(20,10))"

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should study plot method first....